# deleted repeated record and insert id of deleted in another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in the following format:

Table Name  :  PartAtt

in PartAtt I have

```
Id   |   Type   |  Name
-----------------------
1    |    2     |   Bed
2    |    7     |   Bed
3    |    6     |   Sofa
4    |    5     |   Chair
5    |    2     |   Bed
6    |    8     |   Chair
7    |    2     |   Bed
```

So my problem is that I can't have multiple types id's with the same name on this table (i need to clean it up), so I need to  keep the greatest id and then dump the id's of the bad ones in a temp table along with the id of the one saved. So for example:

After cleaning up the table i should have this:

```
Table PartAtt                       #tempTable
    Id   |   Type   |  Name         Id    |   updateId
    -----------------------        --------------------   
    3    |    6     |   Sofa         1    |     7  
    4    |    5     |   Chair        2    |     7
    6    |    8     |   Chair        5    |     7
    7    |    2     |   Bed
```

So far what I am able to do is to find the items that are doubled into a temp table"

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(
 Type int,
 Name varcahar(500)
 )

INSERT INTO #tempTable (Type, Name)
    SELECT Type,Name
        FROM PartAtt
     GROUP BY Type,Name
  HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1 && COUNT(Type) > 1
```

I use this to know which items have the problem, but i cant figure out how delete the oldest records that are twice (type and Name) and insert them into a temp table as above.

I would appreciate some advice and pointers to do this.

Comment: I think some error in data provided.. bed has type "2" but "7" given on 2nd row in original table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below SQL:

**Backup table**

```
CREATE TABLE deleted_PartAtt(Id int, updateId int, Name char(10));
```

**Backup duplicate rows which are going to be removed**

```
INSERT INTO deleted_PartAtt SELECT DISTINCT t1.Id, '', t1.Name FROM PartAtt t1
INNER JOIN PartAtt t2
ON t1.Type = t2.Type AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Id < t2.Id;


UPDATE dp SET dp.updateId = a.Id FROM deleted_PartAtt dp INNER JOIN (SELECT max(t1.Id) AS Id, t1.Name FROM PartAtt t1 INNER JOIN deleted_PartAtt t2
ON t1.Name = t2.Name GROUP BY t1.Name) a ON a.Name = dp.Name;
```

---

**Delete duplicate rows**

```
DELETE t1 FROM PartAtt t1
INNER JOIN PartAtt t2
ON t1.Type = t2.Type AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Id < t2.Id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16729/1)

Answer (score 1):

`Row_number` will be your friend for tonight.

By partitioning by Name, you can assign an increasing number for each duplicate item. Then you keep the items with Row = 1 and dump the rest.

Keep these:

```
select * from 
(
    select *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by ID DESC) as Row
    from PartAtt
) as Temp
where Row = 1
```

Dump these:

```
select * from 
(
    select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by ID DESC) as Row 
    from PartAtt
) as Temp
where Row != 1
```